# A kubeconfig file “/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf” exists already but has got the wrong API Server URL

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I am following https://v1-12.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/ to setup a high avaliablity cluster

three masters : 10.240.0.4 (kb8-master1), 10.240.0.33 (kb8-master2), 10.240.0.75 (kb8-master3)
LB: 10.240.0.16  ( haproxy)

I have setup the kb8-master1 and copied the following files to  rest of the masters  ( kb8-master2 and kb8-master3) as instructed

In the kb8-master2

```
mkdir -p /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd

mv /home/${USER}/ca.crt /etc/kubernetes/pki/

mv /home/${USER}/ca.key /etc/kubernetes/pki/

mv /home/${USER}/sa.pub /etc/kubernetes/pki/

mv /home/${USER}/sa.key /etc/kubernetes/pki/

mv /home/${USER}/front-proxy-ca.crt /etc/kubernetes/pki/

mv /home/${USER}/front-proxy-ca.key /etc/kubernetes/pki/

mv /home/${USER}/etcd-ca.crt /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt

mv /home/${USER}/etcd-ca.key /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.key

mv /home/${USER}/admin.conf /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf

After that I started to follow following commands in the kb8-master2

> `sudo kubeadm alpha phase certs all --config kubeadm-config.yaml`

Output:-

[certificates] Generated etcd/ca certificate and key.

[certificates] Generated etcd/server certificate and key.

[certificates] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [kb8-master2 localhost] and IPs [127.0.0.1 ::1]

[certificates] Generated apiserver-etcd-client certificate and key.

[certificates] Generated etcd/peer certificate and key.

[certificates] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [kb8-master2 localhost] and IPs [10.240.0.33 127.0.0.1 ::1]

[certificates] Generated etcd/healthcheck-client certificate and key.

[certificates] Generated ca certificate and key.

[certificates] Generated apiserver-kubelet-client certificate and key.

[certificates] Generated apiserver certificate and key.

[certificates] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [kb8-master2 kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc 
kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [10.96.0.1 10.240.0.33]

[certificates] Generated front-proxy-ca certificate and key.

[certificates] Generated front-proxy-client certificate and key.

[certificates] valid certificates and keys now exist in "/etc/kubernetes/pki"

[certificates] Generated sa key and public key.

>`sudo kubeadm alpha phase kubelet config write-to-disk --config kubeadm-config.yaml` 

Output:-

[endpoint] WARNING: port specified in api.controlPlaneEndpoint overrides api.bindPort in the controlplane address
[kubelet] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"

>`sudo kubeadm alpha phase kubelet write-env-file --config kubeadm-config.yaml`

Output:-
[endpoint] WARNING: port specified in api.controlPlaneEndpoint overrides api.bindPort in the controlplane address
[kubelet] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"

>`sudo kubeadm alpha phase kubeconfig kubelet --config kubeadm-config.yaml`

Output:-
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"

>`sudo systemctl start kubelet`



>`export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`


>`sudo kubectl exec -n kube-system etcd-kb8-master1 -- etcdctl --ca-file /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert-file /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt --key-file /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key --endpoints=protocol://10.240.0.4:2379 member add kb8-master2 https://10.240.0.33:2380`
```

Output:-
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Note: I can now run kubectl get po -n kube-system in the kb8-master2 to see the pods

```
sudo kubeadm alpha phase etcd local --config kubeadm-config.yaml
```

No output

```
sudo kubeadm alpha phase kubeconfig all --config kubeadm-config.yaml
```

Output:-

***a kubeconfig file "/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf" exists already but has got the wrong API Server URL***

I am really stuck here. Further

Below the kubeadm-config.yaml file I am using in the kb8-master2

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha3
kind: InitConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: v1.12.2
apiServerCertSANs:
- "10.240.0.16"
controlPlaneEndpoint: "10.240.0.16:6443"
etcd:
  local:
    extraArgs:
      listen-client-urls: "https://127.0.0.1:2379,https://10.240.0.33:2379"
      advertise-client-urls: "https://10.240.0.33:2379"
      listen-peer-urls: "https://10.240.0.33:2380"
      initial-advertise-peer-urls: "https://10.240.0.33:2380"
      initial-cluster: "kb8-master1=https://10.240.0.4:2380,kb8-master2=https://10.240.0.33:2380"
      initial-cluster-state: existing
    serverCertSANs:
      - kb8-master2
      - 10.240.0.33
    peerCertSANs:
      - kb8-master2
      - 10.240.0.33
networking:
    podSubnet: "10.244.0.0/16"
```

Have anyone faced the same issue. I am  completely got stuck here

Comment: is this on-premise? what CNI do you use?

Comment: What is the url that is present in `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`?

Comment: I am trying to use flannel.  Also the url in the admin.conf file is server: https://10.240.0.16:6443.

Comment: Also this is on premise.

Comment: I am stuck on this, love to break this curdle to go on with kb8

Comment: I can't open your provided link. But I came acrss this issues whenI run `kubeadm init ---apiserver-advertise-address ip_address ...` twice and use different ip_address, one is the public IP and one is the private IP.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you're individually executing all of the init and join tasks rather than just using init and join outright? Kubeadm is supposed to be extremely trivial to use.

Create your `initConfiguration` and `clusterConfiguraton` manifests and drop them in the same file on your Master. Then create a `nodeConfiguration` manifest and drop it on a file on your nodes. Then on your master run `kubeadm init --config=/location/master.yml` and then on your nodes run `kubeadm join --token 1.2.3.4:6443`

Rather than stepping through the docs for how init and join work specifically with their subtasks, step through [this document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/) to use their automation to build a cluster much more easily.